# Is it possible to create a shared xaml namespace?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Expecting a fairly simple yes / no / why would you want to do this you moron answer.

The vast majority of my files have the exact same namespace declarations.

```
<UserControl x:Class="myNamespace.Views.PageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mvvm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls.Views;assembly=MyNamespace.Controls"
             mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
             AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding PageName}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             d:DesignHeight="618"
             d:DesignWidth="1024" >
```

Adding these namespaces to different pages, autocomplete will sometimes give them different names.  Controls may get called views, mvvm may get changed to prism etc.

Is there any way to declare a default set of namespaces somewhere, and just add that reference to the usercontrol instead?  IE

```
<UserControl x:Class="myNamespace.Views.PageView"
    something="{DynamicResource DefaultControlSetup}">
```

I know there may be very little point to doing something like this, but it's something I got in my head and I'd at least like to know if it's possible, even if it is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't import namespaces using some kind of `DynamicResource` or other markup extension.

These needs to be defined in each XAML file just like you have to add the appropriate `using` directives to each C# source code file.

Comment: Thought that'd be the case.  Thanks for the quick answer.